# Codeigniter: process of creating class->library->and using it. Very simple (if u know how)

Tags: codeigniter

so,

What I want to do is this:

I have a code snippet that hashes passwords. I want to put it in a class, I will call the class from the Controller and will retrieve the returned value of the operation at the class and forward it to the Model.

1. First, from the controller I pass a value to the class of the library

   $params = array('pass' => 'pass');
   $this->load->library('myblowfish', $params);

   1. The class of the library should return 2 values. Don’t know how to write that. Something like this ?

   return array($salt, $hashed_password);

   1. And then the Controller should pick these values and forward them to the Model. I know how to pass them to the Model, but not quite how to receive them from the Class whose values it called.

Comment: cos spy cookies are tracking your previous searches :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to implement your own library?

1. Create and implement your class file in the libraries folder (lets say Password_generator.php with method hash(password) )
2. In the controller, import it by writing $this->library->load('Password_generator');
3. Then call it in your controller by, $hash = $this->password_generator->hash($param);
4. You can pass $hash to the Model now in the way you are used to

If I want to return two values, you can do as you say:

```
$result = array('salt' => $salt, 'hash' => $hash);
return $result;
```

It would accessed like so:

```
$result = $this->password_generator->hash($param);
$salt = $result['salt'];
$hash = $result['hash'];
```

Printing can be accomplished like so:

```
echo 'Salt: '.$salt.'</br>';
echo 'Hash: '.$hash.'</br>';

print_r($result);
```

Are you saying you have tried the above and it hasn't worked?

Although I myself prefer flagged methods like so:

```
function hash($password_param, $opCode = "hash"){
   //... body

   if($opCode == "hash")
        return $hash;
   return $salt;
}
```

The downside to this way is you have to call it twice if you want both.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying, but that is also what I have shown in my code.compare your code with mine. Besides, one of my main problems is how to return 2 values from the library, namely the salt and the password which are produced by the code in there. These 2 values should be picked by the controller. Those are my issues

Comment: alright, that answers the first part of the question. And now, getting to print these items of the array at the Controller.If I manage that, then it is all solved.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this I would do:

**application/libraries/passwords.php**

```
class Passwords {
    public function __construct($pass = null) {
        $this->password = $pass;
    }

    public function hash() {
        $salt = ...;//generate your salt
        $pass = ...;//create your hash
        return array($salt, $pass);
    }
}
```

**application/controllers/yourController.php**

```
class theControler extends CI_Controller {
    ...

    public function hasher ($pass) {
        include './application/libraries/password.php';

        $pass = new Password($pass);
        list($salt, $hash) = $pass->hash();

        //do what you will with the salt and hash
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Greg. I thought one would not use or need to use the include in CI, but everything would be loaded by the controller.

Comment: Thank you guys. Got it finally. I was leaving out the call to the function from the controller once I had loaded the library. In the User guide of CI, they don't explain what to do with the constructors of your class library, what parameters to take, etc. The parameter has to be an array, it won't take a scalar variable, it will complain that argument 1 missing etc. So it is a nice little tool now, I can put aside the long code for hashing in a separate class so that both my controller and model are clean. One would need a lot of comments and explanations though to know where the code hides